# Is it possible to trick expression tree serialization into supporting recursion via a substitute token?

Tags: c#, recursion, expression-trees

We all know that Expression Trees do not support recursion.
I can create a recursive Func, wrap it in an expression tree, and invoke it.

```
Func<int, int> func1 = null;

func1 = x => (x == 0) ? 1 : x * func1(x - 1);

Expression<Func<int, int>> expression1 = i => func1(i);

var func1 = expression1.Compile();

var z1 = func1.Invoke(5);
```

However, when I try to serialize (eg using MetaLINQ) , I of course get an exception as it is a recursive expression.

Lisp constructs expression trees and [supports recursion](http://nostoc.stanford.edu/jeff/llisp/11.html). Genetic Programming mutates expression trees. There are some types of problems whose solutions are inherently recursive, because of prior state they need to track: tree traversal, depth-first search, and divide-and-conquer algorithms. I am aiming to generate efficient algorithms within a managed distributed environment, where branches can be passed around and recombined.

My question is: How could I override the serialization / deserialization to swap out / in the call with a non recursive "mock" token , swapping the recursive call back in when reloading the deserialized tree?

Comment: Lisp constructs expression trees and supports recursion. nostoc.stanford.edu/jeff/llisp/11.html . Genetic Programming mutates expression trees. There are some types of problems whose solutions are inherently recursive, because of prior state they need to track: tree traversal, depth-first search, and divide-and-conquer algorithms.  I am aiming to generate efficient algorithms within a managed distributed environment, where branches can be passed arround and recombined.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an exact answer to your question, but I would apply the Replace Recursion with Iteration Refactoring pattern.

Recursion is usually considered bad, and sometime looked upon as lazy.  I however understand the need to solve the problem first, then refactor the code so that is can be maintained and read with ease.

Comment: Recursion is not considered 'bad', and that kind of 'thinking' is lazy. Many optimal algorithms are recursive - eg Quicksort is often faster than other O(nlogn) sorting algorithms. "The power of recursion lies in the possibility of defining an infinite set of objects by a finite statement - an infinite number of computations can be described by a finite recursive program, even if this program contains no explicit repetitions."

Comment: that 'answer' deserves a -1 ! There are some types of problems whose solutions are inherently recursive, because of prior state they need to track: tree traversal, depth-first search, and divide-and-conquer algorithms. Have you never heard of tail recursion ?

Comment: Please read what I wrote.  I didn't say it was lazy.  I personally think to find a solution (thats what we get paid for) and then refactor the code.  The truth is recursion can be hard to read.  Recursion is a tool on our tool belt.  The problem above can easily be solve with a loop.  Should Josh waste time looking for a way to fit a square peg in a round hold?  Some employers actually like to know a developer can solve a simple recursive problem without recursion.  I don't care either way.  WOW

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you.  I was just trying to help.  I been a developer for since the 80's.  One thing I've learned, is sometimes you have to do things different, because its easier.  I know people who won't allow RAD tools to generate code... If you have the time then that great.  Really the tools are designed to save time so we can solve real problems.  When what the last time you had a user congratulate you on how tight your code was, or how your solution was one of the best they've ever seen.

Comment: [http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html) Please read, as this article actually recommend not using tail recursions.  It states the is is bad.

Comment: I feel for you man.  I am not sure where the anger is coming.  I enjoy working on software teams, and part of doing so involves work with others.  Condescending comments such as "do you know what an algorithm is?", does not help with knowledge sharing.  I work on software that needs to be easily maintained, so my view point is not from a purely academic stand point.  I hope you solve your problem.  Have a good day Josh.

Comment: Lisp constructs expression trees and supports recursion. http://nostoc.stanford.edu/jeff/llisp/11.html . Genetic Programming mutates expression trees. Given that various algorithms I work with are recursive, I am aiming to generate efficient algorithms within a managed distributed environment, where branches can be passed arround and recombined.

Comment: If you needed recursion for a specific reason, why do my comments offend you?  I am simply trying to help a fellow developer.  A small suggestion would be to explain a little about the purpose of your question.  I coding.  I am new to stack overflow and don't get the whole up and down voting and reputation, but do like giving and receiving help from my fellow developers.